# Highcharts add padding to yAxis line numbers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/nye5g9s3/

I have the following chart with a few yAxis and I don't want a title for them.
It does not look good because of the missing padding between the yAxis line to the numbers
How can I fix it?
How can I add padding, and margin to that?

[image]

```
 chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
        id: 'rainfall-axis',
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#08F',
        opposite: true,
          labelsFormat: {
            primaryColor: '#F33',
            secondaryColor: '#F33',
            x: 1,
            y: 1,
            align: 'left',
          },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the spacings by `margin` and `labels.x` properties:

```
  chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
    ...,
    margin: 5,
    labels: {
        x: 0
    }
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wcdfjqsb/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.x

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.margin